# Alphabetical order went wrong, need advice

Tags: bibtex, sorting

My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}

Test \citealt*{dalrymple-etal1991} \citep{dalrymple-etal1998a}

\bibliographystyle{mit-chicago}

\bibliography{test}

\end{document}

%%%test.bib%%%
@article{dalrymple-etal1991,
author = {Mary Dalrymple and Stuart M. Shieber and Fernando C.N. Pereira},
title = {Ellipsis and Higher-Order Unification},
journal = {Linguistics and Philosophy},
year = {1991},
volume = {14},
number = {4},
pages = {399--452},
}

@article{dalrymple-etal1998a,
  author = {Mary Dalrymple and Makoto Kanazawa and Yookyung Kim 
    and Sam Mchombo and Stanley Peters},
title = {Reciprocal Expressions and the Concept of Reciprocity},
journal = {Linguistics and Philosophy},
year = {1998},
volume = {21},
number = {2},
pages = {159--210},
}
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

The order whatever coming is wrong, second entry should come as first and the first should come as second, please advise what went wrong in my tags...

I'm using `LaTeX` (`MikTeX`) and `BIBTeX Version 0.99d` in `Windows7` system.

Comment: I don't seem to have mit-chicago.bst are you sure that bibliography style uses alphabetic ordering?

Comment: Is the file `mit-chicago.bst` file available online somewhere?

Comment: It seems that having more than three authors for the same item gets the bib style into confusion.

Comment: `mit-chicago.bst` file is available at https://github.com/gmarciani/templatex/tree/master/official/mitbook